# How to make scp to use ipv6 addresses?

Tags: ipv6, scp

When I try to use scp over IPv6 addresses I get this:

```
scp -6 osis@::1:/home/osis/test.file ./test.file
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
```

With scp all I ever get is

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
```

using this I get a login into my box without a hitch

```
ssh osis@::1
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`scp` requires some special syntax. The IPv6 address must be enclosed in brackets, which must then be escaped. So in your example it would look like this:

```
scp -6 osis@\[2001:db8:0:1\]:/home/osis/test.file ./test.file
```

Otherwise the first colon ':' is thought to be the separator between the file and the address parts which would result in

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 2001: Address family for hostname not supported
```

In your example with the ip `::1` it is interpreted as if you want to ssh to the host `''` (blank).

Comment: thank you for your answer, this info was somehow missing from man scp;man ssh

Comment: Consider submitting an updated man page, then you can say: I helped.

Comment: When using the -6 flag, you can just type localhost instead of ::1 (which is the IPv6 Address for localhost) to avoid the brackets and therefore any need to escape something on the shell: `scp -6 osis@localhost:/home/osis/test.file ./test.file`

Comment: You are not supposed to use IPv6 addresses, you are supposed to use DNS names.

Comment: Note brackets work only with `scp`, not with `ssh`. Closed as WONTFIX: https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1602

Answer (score 2):

The above command didn't work for me, the error I got was due to v6 address was allowed taking for path.

No need to use back slash "\" . As per the above example below command will work.

```
scp -6 osis@[2001:db8:0:1]:/home/osis/test.file ./test.file
```

Comment: +1 No need to use back slash "\" . As per the above example below command will work.